# Why do certain function on jQuery have strikethrough?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app and I used the following link to build cards in my app

https://codepen.io/marlenesco/pen/NqOozj

I'm using the JavaScript as written, and my cards work fine in localhost. However, the flip button on the cards does not work in the deployed app. I noticed that some functions have a strikethrough, especially the `click` event that I specifically need.

[image]

Any ideas behind this?

Comment: Those are deprecated methods. For event handlers, you should be using the `.on('click', function..` form.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that was my first thought too, but `.click` is not actually listed as deprecated https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler as `.bind` et al. are

Comment: @Jamiec yeah, I should have put deprecated in quotes. It's somebody's idea of what should be deprecated, not what's officially deprecated. IDE makers are free to interpret things as they see fit, so, pick your poison I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those shothand's functions (the click , blur, etc...) are deprecated, you need to replace then with `on` function , take a look here :  https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: click isn't listed as deprecated: https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler nor is blur https://api.jquery.com/blur/#blur-handler - full list: https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: oops, sorry , im talking about the shorthand function